# HTML5 vimeo video not playing in landscape on ipad

Tags: ios-simulator, mobile-safari, html5-video

I haven't done much debugging on ios safari and I am having a strange issue. I need to play HTML5 video from vimeo. The embed code works as expected. If flash player is not detected then HTML5 video is presented to the user.

On desktop all browsers I turn of flash and works fine. On ios using ipad simulator portrait mode in safari the video plays but once I turn it to landscape and load the page and try to click the video to play nothing happens.

If you go to http://tennlife.com:82/drupal/projects/millcitymuseum and navigate to the 3rd slide on the page you can see what I mean.

1. What is the best way to debug this type of thing in the simulator if any.
2. Has anyone run into this type of issue and do you have any suggestions on a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on the Debugging console in iPad and iPhone - http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/14447/step-by-step-turn-on-the-iphone-ipads-web-debugging-console/

Also you can use Firebug Lite to inspect the DOM http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite